# can't receiving message of soap version 1.2 when using axis2 in tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat7, apache-axis

**Enviroment**

O/S : Windows 10

Version Java : 1.7

Version of Tomcat : Tomcat 7

Version Axis2 : 1.6.2

i'm using axis2 in tomcat7. but it can't receiving message of soap version 1.2. what's the problem?

i was tried applied source code like this. but it can't receiving message of soap version 1.2 yet.

**serviceClient.getOptions().setSoapVersionURI(org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAP12Constants.SOAP_ENVELOPE_NAMESPACE_URI);**

http://keithgchapman.blogspot.com/2009/02/axis2-how-to-set-soap-version-on-client.html

this is my source code.

is that anything wrong?

**** services.xml ****

```
<serviceGroup>
   <service name="dispatcher">
      <messageReceivers>
         <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out" class="pkg.test.MessageReceiverV1" />
      </messageReceivers>
   </service>
</serviceGroup>
```

**** MessageReceiverV1.java ****

```
private class MessageReceiverV1 extends org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInMessageReceiver
{

    private MessageReceiverV1 ()
    {
    }

    public void invokeBusinessLogic(org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext inMessage) throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
    {
        // it works good when received soap version of message is 1.1. but when soap version of message is 1.2 that it's not works.
    }
}
```

[image: Result of packet trace in wireshark]